# Is this popular StackOverflow answer incorrect?

Tags: c#, performance, optimization

The post I am referring to is [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380819/common-programming-mistakes-for-net-developers-to-avoid/3743493#3743493) Not only does the first one run faster for me (563 MS compared to 630) when increasing the size to 100000000, but also in the past using properties in for loops has caused considerable speed slowdowns.

Once when writing a waveform viewer every frame took 23 milliseconds on average to process. The for loop that looped through the entire picture's pixels was the cause of the slowdown. Instead of storing the picture's width and height before the for loop I accessed it during each iteration. Upon changing it the time to process a single frame went from 23 milliseconds to a mere 3.

Also, I made this sample class:

```
class LOL
{
    private int x;

    public LOL(int x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int X
    {
        get
        {
            return x;
        }
    }
}
```

I then made a for loop that iterates 500000000 times. One test stored the X in an integer variable before the loop even started and one accessed the X property during each iteration. The former took approximately 1,500 milliseconds and the latter around 8,000.

Three tests and each concludes with the result that storing the limit before-hand being the optimal solution for performance gains. Am I missing something? Currently in my program optimization is required as large pictures are processed and in all performance-critical areas I always store the bounds of the loop before hand for performance gains and these tests seem to confirm that.

Comment: "in the past using properties in for loops has caused considerable speed slowdowns" - that entirely depends on the exact nature of the loop. When doing this *with an array*, the JIT takes a hint and performs some bounds checks elimination for array accesses within the loop. That's not the same as your test which sounds like it wasn't actually doing anything in the loop...

Comment: I assume you run the release version, without the debugger attached?

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges.  The Width and Height property of an image have nothing to do with array sizes.  And yes, they are expensive, it takes a round-trip through unmanaged GDI+ code.  You always want to retrieve them into a local variable before looping on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiled in **release** mode, the **cached length** is faster. On debug it is the opposite.

Test method

```
public static class Performance
{
    public static void Test(string name, decimal times, bool precompile, Action fn)
    {
        if (precompile)
        {
            fn();
        }

        GC.Collect();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        var sw = new Stopwatch();

        sw.Start();

        for (decimal i = 0; i < times; ++i)
        {
            fn();
        }

        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("[{0,15}: {1,-15}]", name, new DateTime(sw.Elapsed.Ticks).ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));
        Debug.WriteLine("[{0,15}: {1,-15}]", name, new DateTime(sw.Elapsed.Ticks).ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
var testAmount = 100;

int[] a1 = new int[10000000];
int[] a2 = new int[10000000];

Performance.Test
(
    "Direct", testAmount, true,
    () =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a1.Length; ++i)
        {
            a1[i] = i;
        }
    }
);

Performance.Test
(
    "Cache", testAmount, true,
    () =>
    {
        var l = a2.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i)
        {
            a2[i] = i;
        }
    }
);
```

**Debug results**

```
[   Direct: 00:00:06.474   ]
[   Cache:  00:00:06.907   ]
```

**Release results**

```
[   Direct: 00:00:05.382   ]
[   Cache:  00:00:04.714   ]
```

Comment: My numbers are very different; I basically get the same timings in this scenario - nothing like the "Release results" you cite. In Debug, the cached version is notably slower.

Answer (score 5):

No, it looks right to me; if I run this:

```
int[] values = new int[100000000];

var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
int length = values.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    values[i] = i;
watch.Stop();
var hoisted = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    values[i] = i;
watch.Stop();
var direct = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

and build with optimisations, running from the console; I get `direct` as 71 and `hoisted` as 163, which ties into what I would expect from the JIT eliminating the out-of-bounds check on a vector (but only when accessed directly).

Comment: They are both around the same speeds for me but the second one is slightly faster. I think the reason the first one was faster for me earlier was because I started the Stopwatch after storing the length. I guess that doesn't make much sense. Regardless, thanks the reply. I understand now =)

Comment: You know, if I reverse the order in which your tests occur (direct first and hoisted second), compile in `Release` with optimizations on, I get opposite results.  hoisted is ~84ms and direct is ~150ms.  When I took your code as you pasted it in, I had opposite results (i.e. direct was faster).

Comment: @David hmm.... I *think* that points to different scenarios in which the JIT does / doesn't make the optimisation. I can't repro your numbers, but I can get them to be the same - meaning: it didn't apply the optimise

Comment: @David I also got opposite results.

Comment: @BrunoLM - I wonder if the initialization of those methods (aren't they JIT'ed?) adds a bit of overhead and potentially skews the results.  I'm just guessing, though.